# Make batch file with powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, smtp

I have done the commands that I want to send mail in `Powershell`. This is my code

```
powershell.exe
$user="username@gamil.com"
$pass=cat I:\password.txt | convertto-securestring
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user, $pass
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Credential $mycred -Usessl true -From 'username@gamil.com' -To 'usernametwo@gamil.com' -Subject 'failure Test'
```

Above code is working fine when I execute in command prompt, but not When I try to make a `.bat` file. What is the problem I have done with code?

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: When I try to execute `.bat` file, the commmand prompt open and execute `poweshell.exe` and stops, like this `I:\>powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS I:\>`

Comment: try removing powershell.exe from the file and save it as .ps1 then create a .bat file and write powershell.exe -file myscript.ps1

Comment: Cheers. I'll post it below so you can select it as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove powershell.exe from the file and save it as .ps1 then create a .bat file and write powershell.exe -file myscript.ps1

Bat file:

```
powershell.exe -file myscript.ps1
```

myScript.ps1:

```
$user="username@gamil.com"
$pass=cat I:\password.txt | convertto-securestring
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user, $pass
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Credential $mycred -Usessl true -From 'username@gamil.com' -To 'usernametwo@gamil.com' -Subject 'failure Test'
```